# Using Carbon in Eloquent Query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

Good day everyone,

I'm currently realising a system that lets colleagues fill in their worked hours and what they worked on. I save those into the database using a time_stamp (date) named in the table. Now I have been trying to get the values of the filled in registrations of last week (I created some dummy times). And I have been trying to use Carbon and the Eloquent query builder at the same time, and i'm completely stuck. Would anyone mind to help me out?

```
$currentDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now('GMT+2');

    $agoDate = $currentDate->subDays($currentDate->dayOfWeek)->subWeek();

    $weekly = Hoursregistration::pluck('date')->agoDate($currentDate);
    return $weekly;
```

Is the code that should pick up the dates from the db (which works). But when I try to put in the variables containing the carbon methods. It doesnt work and throw me a Method agoDate does not exist. (View: /var/www/clients/client0/web319/web/resources/views/hoursregistrations/index.blade.php) error.

I would love some help as this is crucial to my education (kind of in a tight spot rn.)

Comment: agoDate is not an existing method within the Carbon library - what do you exactly want to achieve? Getting the date minus one day?

Comment: All recorded items of the last week

Comment: Since my boss told me to use Carbon for date handling, and an Eloquent query for getting the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you ask for: all `Hoursregistration` records from `1 week ago` until `now`

```
// Current date + GMT(+2) as stated in your question
$currentDate = Carbon::now('GMT+2');

// Date exactly 1 week ago
$agoDate = $currentDate->subDays($currentDate->dayOfWeek)->subWeek();

// Records with date -between- two values
// $weekly = Hoursregistration::whereBetween('date', [$agoDate, Carbon::now('GMT+2')])->get();

// Or even simpler, all records where date is 'higher' than 1 week ago
$weekly = Hoursregistration::where('date', '>', $agoDate)->get();

// Getting the dates with the `pluck` method on the returned $weekly collection
$dates = $weekly->pluck('date');

return $weekly;
```

Comment: Man Liam, you are the best. Just... one last request though. I am wondering how It would be possible to.. show the data of last week using a dropdown (going back a month). by selecting for instance: Data of 24th april - 1st may). If I could get some help with that, that would make my already sad day

Comment: That's a bit out of this questions' scope, so you might want to post a new question on SO for that, after you tried it a bit yourself.

Comment: I've been trying all day today without any progress

Comment: Post a new question on SO